# How to migrate MongoDB schema to SQL Server model "EF-Core"?

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework, .net-core

I have the following MongoDB schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        email: { type: String, unique: true },

        tokens: [{ accessToken: String, kind: String }],

        permissions: [Number],
        registration: { type: String, match: /(CLIENT|CUSTOMER|UNKOWN)/ },

        profile: {
            name: String,
            gender: String,
            location: String,
            website: String,
            picture: String,
        },

        clientCategories: [String],
    },
    { timestamps: true },
);
```

and I want to implement the same model for SQL Server and  EF Core, I tried the following implementation

```
public class UserModel : IBaseUserModel
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required, EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ICollection<AccessToken> AccessTokens { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ICollection<int> Permissions { get; set; }

    [Required, RegularExpression(@"^CLIENT|CUSTOMER|UNKOWN$")]
    public string Registration { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

/// <summary> 
///     Basic user properties
/// </summary>
public interface IBaseUserModel
{
    long Id { get; set; }

    string Email { get; set; }

    ICollection<AccessToken> AccessTokens { get; set; }

    ICollection<int> Permissions { get; set; }

    string Registration { get; set; }

    Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
///     The definition of the AccessToken
/// </summary>
public struct AccessToken { public string key, provider; }

/// <summary>
///     The definition of the User's Profile
/// </summary>
public struct Profile { public string name, gender, location, avatar; }
```

but I got an error

> The property 'UserModel.AccessTokens' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'AccessToken[]' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I know that there are `type conversions` supported in EF Core but I don't know how to use this thing as it's the first time for me to work with this framework, thanks in advance.

<del>**Sidenote** the reason I'm using `abstract` class is that I'm going to extend other classes from that one, like `public class CustomerModel : UserModel, ICustomer { }`</del>

Comment: Use `ICollection<AccessToken>` and you may have to change `AccessToken` to a `class`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto but using `class` means that this property going to have separated table into the database?

Comment: Of course it does. How do you expect to put multiple rows inside a single one?

Comment: isn't this the reason of `type conversions` to convert this struct into a string or another type? please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Are you talking about [value conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)? If so, I don't see where you defined that in your code

Comment: yes that's what I mean, but I don't know how to use it and this page mentioned the native types, not the custom structs or even how to write my own converter.

Comment: It doesn't tell you how to write your own? That's the very first example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions#configuring-a-value-converter

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that example wasn't so clear but it is now, and thanks for the `ICollection` advice it was helpful.

Comment: FYI - If you only want to use EF Core, you don't have to switch to SQL. You can use [MongoDB with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio), as well. Even if you really do want to switch to SQL, it might make sense to change one thing at a time (e.g. implement EF Core + MongoDB, then migrate your MongoDB to SQL Server) to reduce variables.

Answer (score 0):

`type conversions` wasn't so clear for me but it makes sense now, the following code did the trick

```
protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var StringListToStringConverter = new ValueConverter<ICollection<string>, string>(_strings => string.Join(";", _strings), _string => _string.Split(new[] { ';' }));
    var IntListToStringConverter = new ValueConverter<ICollection<int>, string>(_ints => string.Join(";", _ints), _string => Array.ConvertAll(_string.Split(new[] { ';' }), int.Parse));
    var AccessTokenToStringConverter = new ValueConverter<ICollection<AccessToken>, string>(_token => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_token), _string => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<AccessToken>>(_string));
    var ProfileToStringConverter = new ValueConverter<Profile, string>(_token => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_token), _string => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Profile>(_string));

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<UserModel>()
        .Property(e => e.Permissions)
        .HasConversion(IntListToStringConverter);

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<UserModel>()
        .Property(e => e.AccessTokens)
        .HasConversion(AccessTokenToStringConverter);

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<UserModel>()
        .Property(e => e.Profile)
        .HasConversion(ProfileToStringConverter);

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<ClientModel>()
        .Property(e => e.Categories)
        .HasConversion(StringListToStringConverter);
}
```

I think that converting properties unto string and store them in the same table is better than saving each property into new table.

Comment: Just note that using a relational database to store non-relational data is extremely weird. I would suggest you to either normalize this data or use a non-relational database

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I used to use the non-relational databases, so my main point here is that I think that separating models into dozens of tables is a bad abroach for performance, please fix me if I wrong, I also may consider using caching and separated tables for better performance.